# Google map in Sherlock Tab

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I have a tab navigation working ( 2 tabs). In the second tab, I want to insert a google map object.

Code for using tabs :

```
public class FragmentTabsTienda extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
private static String TAG = "TabActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frag_pdvs);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Lista");
    tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_view_as_list);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    tab2.setText("Mapa");
    tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location_map);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("");

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    // create the two fragments we want to use for display content

    tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener<ListTiendaTabFragment>(this,
            "lista", ListTiendaTabFragment.class));
    tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener<MapTiendasTabFragment>(this,
            "mapa", MapTiendasTabFragment.class));

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    // tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fMapTiendas));
}

public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /**
     * Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
     * 
     * @param activity
     *            The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
     * @param tag
     *            The identifier tag for the fragment
     * @param clz
     *            The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
     */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("camara").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_device_access_camera)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    menu.add("chat").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_social_chat)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    menu.add("settings").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

}
```

In the first tab, my list is displaying well.
But I can't display my map :

This is the code for the tab I want to display the map:

```
public class MapTiendasTabFragment extends SherlockFragment {
GoogleMap mMap = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mMap = initMap();
}

private GoogleMap initMap() {

    if (mMap == null) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map); // is null !!
        mMap = smf.getMap();

    } else {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Iniciar centrado en Mexico
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                19.506467, -99.131417), 4));
    }

    return mMap;
}
}
```

and the associated xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_map"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/maps_unavailable"
        style="@style/placeholder_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/maps_unavailable"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="4.0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:background="@drawable/inset_bottom_shadow" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ab_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
<!-- 
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/map_pager_height" />
 -->
</LinearLayout>
```

In my code , the SupportMapFragment smf is null, I can't get any value !!!
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

The problem were resolved with this gist : 
https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {

MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

}
```

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as they can break. Please pull relevant information from your link into this answer so that the information is still available even if the link isn't.